# Extract Chrome Live Caption Programmatically

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Anybody knows how i can integrate programmatically with chrome Live Caption ?
I want to extract the caption data in specific form(subtitle style) but i don't know how or even finding a way to achieve my target.please help

Comment: I guess pipe a HTML5 `MediaStream` into  https://github.com/MidCamp/live-captioning ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.